# JavaScript - Checkbox onchange function is not executing the whole way through

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, onchange

I have an input of type checkbox with an onchange event as shown below:

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="cbWarehouse" onchange="disableAllButtons()"/>

<script>
    function disableAllButtons()
    {
        // gvDetail
        var gvDetail = document.getElementById("<%=gvDetail.ClientID %>");
        var gvDetailControls = gvDetail.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i < gvDetailControls.length; i++)
        {
            gvDetailControls[i].disabled = true;
        }

        // gvSummary
        var gvSummary = document.getElementById("<%=gvSummary.ClientID %>");
        var gvSummaryControls = gvSummary.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i < gvSummaryControls.length; i++)
        {
            gvSummaryControls[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This function's purpose is to disable all buttons in two GridViews - `gvSummary` and `gvDetail`. However, it only disables the buttons in whichever GridView I mention first in the JS function. I.e. in the example above, the buttons in `gvDetail` will be disabled but not in `gvSummary`.

So it seems that the function stops halfway through..?

Anyone have any ideas where I am going wrong?

****EDIT (RESOLVED)****

Issue was resolved by checking that each GridView was defined and not null:

```
<script>
    function disableAllButtons()
    {
        // gvSummary
        var gvSummary = document.getElementById("<%=gvSummary.ClientID %>");
        if (typeof (gvSummary) != 'undefined' && gvSummary != null)
        {
            var gvSummaryControls = gvSummary.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < gvSummaryControls.length; i++) {
                gvSummaryControls[i].disabled = true;
                gvSummaryControls[i].className = "btn-xs btn-secondary";
            }
            gvSummary.title = "You have unapplied filters. Pleae update table.";
        }
        // gvDetail
        var gvDetail = document.getElementById("<%=gvDetail.ClientID %>");
        if (typeof (gvDetail) != 'undefined' && gvDetail != null)
        {
            var gvDetailControls = gvDetail.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < gvDetailControls.length; i++) {
                gvDetailControls[i].disabled = true;
                gvDetailControls[i].className = "btn-xs btn-secondary";
            }
            gvDetail.title = "You have unapplied filters. Pleae update table.";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: any browser developer tools console errors to indicate a problem?

Comment: If your code appears to stop executing mid-function, that usually indicates that your javascript is throwing an exception. Check the console for errors. Also, code smell: `for(i = 0`, consider using `for(var i = 0`, otherwise you're creating a global variable `i`, which can be modified from the outside and interfere with your iteration. If we're seeing your entire `for` block here, I don't really see that this is likely to be your problem, but it's still a best practice to put it in there.

Comment: @DavidHedlund preferably (pre ES2015) declare `var i` before first loop if you use it in two places :p

Comment: @Jaro: Fair point. Anyway, as it stands, whatever is causing the error is not in the code presented. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gwq1dg30/). On another note, we might also mention that the entire content of `disableAllButtons` can be reduced to a silly and less old-browser-compatible oneliner: `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#gvDetail input, #gvSummary input')).forEach(function(x) { x.disabled = true; });`

Comment: I think it may be failing because only one GridView is visible at a time. Is there a way you can check for GridView visibility in JS? And thanks for the code tips!

Comment: @DavidHedlund - or even more simply `Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#gvDetail input, #gvSummary input'), function(x) { x.disabled = true; });` or even `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#gvDetail input, #gvSummary input'), function(x) { x.disabled = true; });` - and then we could descend into ES2015+ code :p

Comment: @Johnathan - wouldn't that mean the order of the two "blocks" was irrelevant?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, it would. The function works for whichever GridView comes first in the function because otherwise it wouldn't find the GridView and throws an exception.

Comment: I believe when a webforms control is set to not visible it simply isn't rendered, so you can just check if the result of your getElementById is null before you proceed to call getElementsByTagName on it.